# Correct way to use eigen library (with cmake and using vscode)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, eigen

I want to properly set up the installation of eigen for ros projects. I want to use CMake as it is used with ros and i am using the VSCode IDE. I think i almost set it up, but vscode throws me an error. So, i will present my whole process so far in order to:

1. double check my understanding of what i accomplished in each step
2. present the error in vcode.

**Installation process i followed**

I downloaded the eigen library and then installed it using cmake:
In the folder where i extracted the `eigen-3.4.0.tar.gz` file (`~/Eigen/eigen-3.4.0`)i did the following:

```
mkdir build
cd build 
cmake ../
sudo make install
```

The header files are now copied in `/usr/local/include` so i can easily include them in any c++ project using:  `#include <eigen3/Eigen/<header> >` . This is possible because i ran `make install`, and the default install path is `/usr/local`.  However, as i intend to use eigen for ros projects, i want to include the library using cmake (In order to package my programms for other people).

**Using CMake for included files**

I have the following file structure:

```
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
```

From [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCMakeGuide.html), the required cmake code to include the library in my .cpp file is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(eigenTest)

find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED)

add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} src/eigenTut.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}  Eigen3::Eigen)
```

As i installed just the header files, using `find_package`, cmake searches for everything that it needs to include in `~/Eigen/eigen-3.4.0/build` folder, where the file `Eigen3Config.cmake` is located.

I can now run the following commands inside the build folder :

```
cmake ../
make
```

and i have a working executable.

**Using VScode**

However, VSCode throws me an error:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/home/<user>/Documents/Programming/LearnCpp/src/eigenTut.cpp).
```

Should i update the include bath for every project to include  `~/Eigen/eigen-3.4.0/**` or is there a way to cleverly include the libraries i specify in CMakeLists.txt?

**Edit 1:**
When i added `~/Eigen/eigen-3.4.0/**` to the include path of VScode, the error stopped appearing and using F12 (Go to references) i go to the source code. However, i cannot run the code:

```
eigenTut.cpp:4:10: fatal error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <Eigen/Dense>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The code i am testing is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Eigen::MatrixXd;
 
int main()
{
  MatrixXd m(2,2);
  m(0,0) = 3;
  m(1,0) = 2.5;
  m(0,1) = -1;
  m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
  std::cout << m << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**Edit 2** I am using the CMakeTools and the C/C++ extensions. Also, i am in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: This might end up somewhat opinion-based, largely due to the opinionated nature of third-party integration with C++ projects. I prefer vcpkg in manifest mode, added as a git submodule. You clone recursively, run cmake, and your project is ready to go. Others prefer Conan, and others still prefer to keep it all in cmake. Or, you can still require that others do a global install like you did. I don't see there being a "right" way.

Comment: Did you set [`configurationProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) to `"ms-vscode.cmake-tools"` yet? You can set the default in your workspace settings.json, or set it in each c_cpp_properties configuration.

Comment: I added that now, but still i cannot use the  "Run Code" option. I have to manually go to build folder and then: `cmake ../`-> `make`and run the resulting excecutable.

Comment: You need to run the `CMake: Configure` command whenever your build configuration changes (by default it will happen automatically when you save edits to your main CMakeLists.txt file), and run the `CMake: Build` command to run build. In any case, did my first suggestion solve the problem shown in your question post? I can write up an answer post.

Comment: no it didn't solve my problem. I still cannot use the `Run Code` from VScode. I can build the excecutable from the terminal, and it works. But not automatically through vscode.